# Ionic 2: Loop through list of objects

Tags: angular, loops, ionic2

I am trying to create a view that displays a list of clients and I'm running into an issue due to the fact that it's an object and because of Ionic's html types.

Here is my object:

```
x = { Consultation: [{name: "Joe Smith}, {name: "Jane Doe"}],
   Re-evaluation: [{name: "Joe Smith2}, {name: "Jane Doe2"}],
   Meeting: [{name: "Joe Smith3}, {name: "Jane Doe3"}],
   Testing: [{name: "Joe Smith4}, {name: "Jane Doe4"}]
}
```

and I define `appointment_types` as `Object.keys(x)` aka `["Consultation", "Re-evaluation", "Meeting", "Testing"]`.

In my view:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-list-header *ngFor="let type of appointment_types">{{ type }}</ion-list-header>

  <!-- type is no longer defined after ion-list-header closes -->
  <ion-item-sliding class="shaded-slider" *ngFor="let client of appointment_types[type]"> 
    <ion-item>{{ client.name }}</ion-item>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

Is there something I can do to stay inside the `appointment_types` loop?

Comment: Iin order to access `type` *object* in `<ion-item-sliding`, you should put the first `*ngFor` in the `ion-list`.

Comment: Try adding a div with your ngFor that encompasses all. like <div *ngFor="let type of appointment_type><ion-item-sliding *ngFor...></ion-item-sliding></div>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this by having your iteration of the type in `ion-list`:

```html
<ion-list *ngFor="let type of appointment_types">
```

and then when you have the `type` and your original object `x`, you can iterate the `x` object with inner arrays like:

```html
<ion-item-sliding class="shaded-slider" *ngFor="let client of x[type]">
```

So your complete template would look like this:

```html
<ion-list *ngFor="let type of appointment_types">
  <ion-list-header >{{ type }}</ion-list-header>
  <ion-item-sliding class="shaded-slider" *ngFor="let client of x[type]"> 
    <ion-item>{{ client.name }}</ion-item>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

Here's a **[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/g7FK0a6cWmd354NsINA1?p=preview)**

Comment: I was thinking that, but I know their `<ion-list>` elements have pre-determined CSS and I wasn't sure if I really wanted to re-create a list with each iteration

Comment: Not really understanding what you mean with your comment, but that might very well be because of that I haven't used ionic except here on SO :) But if you want to somehow build this differently, you could also wrap it with `<ng-container *ngFor="....."></ng-container>` but I don't know how that affects the rest of the code css-wise. But you can experiment and see how it would play out :)